# JsonServiceClient seems to not be included in assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, servicestack, nuget

In continuing to learn about and use ServiceStack, I'm trying to consume the hello service with a c#/WPF application.

I've gone through the expected step of using NuGet to install the required files:

```
PM> install-package servicestack.common
```

I believe I have imported the correct namespaces:

```
using ServiceStack.Common;
using ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web;
```

Yet when I attempt to follow the examples I've found on Stack and Github, VS10 reports that the type or namespace cannot be found.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://172.16.0.15/");
```

I am also unable create this object using what I believe to be the fully qualified name:

```
var client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.web.JsonServiceClient . . .
```

Is there another package that must be installed or another reference that must be made in order to use this class?

**Update:**

The fully qualified type as suggested by Darin doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
var client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("http://172.16.0.15/");
```

I still get VS10 reporting:

```
"The type or namespace name 'ServiceClient' does not exist in the namespace 'ServiceStack'.... "
```

Comment: I just created a fresh console application in VS2010, installed servicestack.common using nuget, and I was able to create an instance of JsonServiceClient. If you view the references for your project do you see ServiceStack.Common listed?

Comment: Yeah I see: ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Common/Interfaces/OrmLite/OrmLite.SqlServer/Redis/ServiceInterface/Text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct namespace is:

```
using ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web;
```

It's not:

```
ServiceStack.Common
```

and it's not:

```
ServiceStack.Common.ServiceClient.Web
```

and it's not:

```
ServiceStack.ServiceClient.web
```

So either bring the correct namespace into scope with the using keyword or fully qualify the type:

```
var client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("http://172.16.0.15/");
```

Comment: This seems to have been one part of the problem. The other part was the .net profile that I was using. I switched FROM ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" TO ".NET Framework 4"